# In CloudFormation, store a Subnet ID in Parameter Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, aws-parameter-store

I have a CloudFormation template to create a VPC and add a subnet and security group to it. I need to store the new security group's ID and the subnet's ID in AWS Parameter Store.

This works fine for the security group using `Value: !GetAtt [securityGroup, GroupId]` in the , but I can't figure out how to reference the subnet's ID in a way that works with Parameter Store.

Here are the relevant parts of the CloudFormation:

```yaml
Resources:

### Subnet resource ###

  subnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Ref SubnetAvailabilityZone1
      CidrBlock: 10.2.0.0/16
      VpcId: !Ref requesterVpc

### Parameter Store resource ###

  subnet1Id:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Description: Lambda Subnet ID
      Name: /lambda-vpc/subnet/1
      Value: !GetAtt [subnet1, id] # <---------- this doesn't work        (Error A below)
      Value: !Ref subnet1          # <---------- this doesn't work either (Error B below)
```

### Error A

Attempting to get the 'id' attribute of the subnet understandably gives the error

> resource subnet1 does not support attribute type id in Fn::GetAtt.

I also tried "SubnetId" to no avail. Looking at the [subnet's CF documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html) shows there's no attribute for the subnet's ID returnable with `Fn::GetAtt`.

### Error B

Attempting to get the subnet ID using `Fn::Ref` doesn't work either. Even though the documentation says "`Ref` returns the ID of the subnet", trying to update the CF stack gives this error when it attempts to create/update the "subnet1Id" parameter:

> Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/}: [Value]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the AWS resource type I was using for the parameters.

I was using `AWS::SecretsManager::Secret`, but I needed `AWS::SSM::Parameter`. After switching to that and adding `Type: String` to Properties, `!Ref subnet1` worked.

Comment: In addition to this I recommend exploring the CDK which may help make some of this simpler for you in the future. It is IaC and runs in many different languages including .Net Core, Python, Typescript and Java.